# how can i check for one value, multiple values satisfy or not and if they do record it?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, conditional-statements

Suppose there is a two arrays:

> a = [2, 4];  b = [16, 48, 96];

and the third array is :

> c = [4, 8, 12];

I have to check if, for `c[0]`, every item of `a` and `b` is divided then count it.

Otherwise, don't then go for other `c` values further.

Comment: So you want to divide each item in a and b by each item in c?

Comment: YES and if it does divide every item of a and b then only count

Comment: I tried with loops but couldn't figure out..:(

Comment: Do you mean if any item in both `a` and `b` is divisible by an item in `c` (i.e. `c[0] = 4`, and the ones divisible by 4 are `a[1], b[0], b[1], b[2]`)? Or do you mean to check if any value in array `b`, divided by any item in array `a`, is equal to an item in `c` (i.e. for `c[0] == b[0] / a[1]`)? Or something else? Could you perhaps add what your expected output is for the three arrays you've provided?

Comment: Actually i have to check for the item in c for which every item in a is a factor and every item in b is divided...so if,for c[0], c[0]%a[0]==0 && b[0]%c[0]==0 then the condition will satisfy and i have to take only that item of c which satisfy above condition.

Comment: Can you add the expected output to your question?

Comment: Yes the expected output should be [4,8] only as 2,4 of 'a' evenly divide 4, 8, 12 of 'c' and 4 and 8 only of c divide 16, 48, 96 of b......so 4,8 should be answer as every item of a is factor of it and every item of b is divided by them.

Comment: You should show what you already tried, not just blatantly ask for a solution. [mcve]

Comment: Oh m sorry in that case...anyway Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't understand you wrong , here is what you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int a [] = {2,4};
    int b [] = {16,48,96};
    int c [] = {4,8,12};
    int result [] = {0,0,0};
    for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
        boolean check = true;

        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
            if(c[i]%a[j]!=0){
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int k=0;k<b.length;k++){
            if(c[i]%b[k]!=0){
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(check){
            result[i] = c[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The result array contains elements from array c which is divided for all a and b arrays' element.

Comment: YES...I think it should work fine.....only difference is in second loop the if condition should be if( b[k] % c[i] != 0)...i couldn't thought that boolean is a solution...Thanks a lot..really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
boolean dividesEveryItem = true;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length) {
    if (a[i] % c[0] != 0) {
        dividesEveryItem = false;
        break;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < b.length) {
    if (b[i] % c[0] != 0) {
        dividesEveryItem = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (dividesEveryItem) {
    // Count
}
```

Comment: got your point...using boolean i could have done that easily...Thanks...:)